# Android Navigation Drawer Example with WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-fragments

I am using the Android Navigation Drawer Example [LINK](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) .
I also have worked with a WebView before and I wanted to integrate a WebView in the Example instead of showing an image.
I am really new to this stuff.

I have replaced

```
        @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item_image, container, false);
        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_MENUITEM_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
```

with

```
        @Override
    public WebView onCreate(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        WebView webView = (WebView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_item_webview, container, false);
        // Ignoring menu item / planet - showing same content on every page
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                // Handle the error
            }

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
            {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.de");
        return webView;
    }
```

Compiling is OK - No errors. Every menu item ends in a white page.
Perhaps someone could give me a hint how to find what I am doing wrong.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

How can it compile? You can't replace the fragment's onCreateView method with public WebView onCreate. I suggest you read more about Fragments [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

If you want a WebView, inflate it from XML like in the original example, but instead of an ImageView, declare a WebView.